# Understanding contradiction in proof of Algorithm for Testing of Clustering of points in metric space in sub-linear time

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, approximation, clustering, streaming-algorithm

I am trying to understand [this paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos598B/bib/alon00testing.pdf), in which (k, b)-clusterability  is defined like so:

A set $X$ of points in a metric space is (k, b)-diameter clusterable if $X$ can be partitioned into $k$ subsets (clusters) such that the maximum distance between any pair of points in a cluster is $b$.

The paper offers an algorithm that rejects A set $X$ if it is $\epsilon-far$ from (k-2b)-clusterable with probability > $\frac{2}{3}$.

$\epsilon-far$ from (k-2b)-clusterable here means that at least $\epsilon |X|=\epsilon n$ points must be deleted from $X$ in order to make it (k-2b)-clusterable.

**Algorithm 1 (in page 4):**

1. Let $rep_1$ be an arbitrary point in $X$ (a representative for the first cluster).
2. $i=1$ $find\_new\_rep=True$
3. While $i<k+1$ and $find\_new\_rep==True$

   3.1 Uniformly and independently select a sample of size $ln(3k)/\epsilon$

   3.2 If there exists a point $x$ in the sample, such that $dist(x, rep_j)>b$ for every $j\le i$, then $i=i+1$; $rep_i=x$

   3.3. Else (all points in the sample are at distance at most b from some $rep_j$), $find\_new\_rep = False$
4. If $i\le k$ Accept, Else Reject.

---

I am struggling with the very last part of the proof (Theorem 1 in page 4):

> ... Hence, from now on, assume that $X$ is $\epsilon$-far from $(k, 2b)$ -clusterable ...
> Consider any particular iteration. We say that a point $x \in X$ is a
> *candidate representative* with respect to $rep_1, ..., rep_i$ if it has distance greater than $b$ from each of these points. We claim that
> as long as $i \le k$ there must be more than $\epsilon n$ such
> candidate representatives.   Assume in contradiction that there are at
> most $\epsilon n$ such points. Then we could remove these points from
> $X$, and for every other point $y \in X$, assign y to a cluster $j$
> such that $dist(y, rep_j) \le b$. By the triangle inequality, the
> diameter of each resulting cluster is at most $2b$, **which
> contradicts out assumption concerning $X$**.

What I seem to miss is **what is the contradiction**?

I can see why every cluster is of diameter $2b$, but I don't see why ignoring all far points, and adding the rest to some valid clusters gives anything not OK.

Would love some direction as I have been staring at this for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the problem the paper is trying to solve is a gap problem of deciding whether $X$ is $(k,b)$-clusterable, or at least $\epsilon$-far from being $(k,2b)$-clusterable. Since they explained why the algorithm always accepts when $X$ is $(k,b)$-clusterable, now they move on to explain what happens when $X$ is at least $\epsilon$-far from being $(k,2b)$-clusterable.

Now, their job is to show that there are a lot of candidates in $X$ at any point in time (so the probability of choosing at least one will be high). They **assume towards contradiction** this is not the case. That is, they assume that sometime they reach a state where there are *less* than $\epsilon \cdot n$ candidates. Here comes the tricky part: They want to show this contradicts the fact we know $X$ is $\epsilon$-far from being $(k,2b)$-clusterable, so they remove the $\epsilon \cdot n$ candidates from $X$, and explain why we are left with at most $k$ clusters of size $2b$: Each $y\in X$ that is left, is not a candidate. Hence, there must be some representative $rep_i$ such that $dist(y,rep_i)\le b$. They define the clusters to be balls with radius $b$ around all those representatives, and overall each point $y$ must be in at least one ball. The balls have a radius of $b$, so the distance between any two points in them is at most $2b$ (the diameter of the ball). Therefore, they found a $(k,2b)$-clustering of $X$ when we remove those $\epsilon \cdot n$ points. But since $X$ was assumed to be *far* from such a clustering (you need to remove *more* than $\epsilon \cdot n$ to convert it into something clusterable), this contradicted that assumption.

Hence, they conclude that at each point in time there are at least $\epsilon \cdot n$ possible candidates.

Comment: Saved my weekend once again :)